# UIButton closes UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

How can I dismiss a UIView that is over the main content? Think of it as a tour popup window with a close button.  Here is the code I am using, but it's not working.  No errors, or warnings, just doesn't seem to be doing the trick.  Any ideas?

```
    - (void) showUserSettings {
        UIView *settingsPopover = [[UIView alloc] init];
        settingsPopover.frame = CGRectMake(20, 600, 280, 350);
         [settingsPopover.layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(241/255.0) green:(241/255.0) blue:(241/255.0) alpha:1].CGColor];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{
            settingsPopover.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 130, 280, 350);
            settingsPopover.alpha = 1.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        }];


        UIButton *closeSettings = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(245, 0, 35, 40)];
        [closeSettings setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(212/255.0) green:(121/255.0) blue:(146/255.0) alpha:1]];
        [closeSettings setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [closeSettings addTarget:self action:@selector(closeSettings) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [settingsPopover addSubview:closeSettings];
        [self.view addSubview:settingsPopover];
    }

    - (void) closeSettings {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{
        _settingsPopover.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 400, 280, 350);
        _settingsPopover.alpha = 1.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         [_settingsPopover removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Set breakpoints and make sure the code is stepping through as you designed it.

Comment: are you sure that the button is inside closeSettings? try to change the background color of the button,if it is outside the bound of the settingsPopOver touchEvents won't work

Comment: The button definitely sees the touchEvent.  When I do something silly like adding another UIView when the close button is clicked it works fine.  For some reason I just can't get it to dismiss the UIView.

Comment: **UIView *settingsPopover = [[UIView alloc] init];** U creating a settingPopover inside a method call with local-variable but u removing the **_settingPopover** in remove statement.

Comment: Where should the settingsPopover be created if not in a (void) @CoolMonster

Comment: @user3167213 Check my answer mate. What you actually did was created a local variable called `settingsPopover` but then you try to remove something else from the superView called `_settingsPopover`. All you need to do is add one line and modify another line in your `showUserSettings` method.

Comment: I think Pavan has answered your question since you didn't initialize the iVar _settingsPopover, but in close settings you were trying to remove it.

Comment: @CoolMonster you and I rock ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to remove a view that was locally created but you had no reference to it later on when you tried to remove it from the superview.

This is what you did, you created and init'ed a new UIView called `settingsPopover`

```
UIView *settingsPopover = [[UIView alloc] init];    
...
[self.view addSubview:settingsPopover];
```

And then you're removing **another** view called `_settingsPopover` which has no association to your locally created view in the `showUserSettings` method.

I assume you have created a global variable of type `UIView` called `_settingsPopover`. And if that is the case, which it should be then in your `-(void)showUserSettings` method add one line and change another line to fix it all. Have a look below:

```
-(void)showUserSettings{
    ...
    [settingsPopover addSubview:closeSettings]; <-- in your method the code up to here is fine

    // add this line before your addsubview code
    _settingsPopover = settingsPopover; //We are copying over your local variable to your global variable

    //and change this line from 'settingsPopover' to '_settingsPopover'
    [self.view addSubview:_settingsPopover];
```

This way your newly created variable of type view called `settingsPopover` that you created locally in the `showUserSettings` method will be copied to your global variable called `_settingsPopover` variable, and thats the variable you want to add as a subview.

This way you can reference to it later on when you want to remove it from the superView which you already are doing with `[_settingsPopover removeFromSuperview];` in your `closeUserSettings` method.
All your other code is fine.

Comment: Any time buddy @user3167213

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing here can also be termed as **"Implementing splash screen"**. Splash screen is nothing but a quick visual tutorial for user, intended to give a quick look of the features.

Here is a [good tutorial](http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/iphone-dev-how-to-implement-a-splash-screen/) about implementing Splash screen in iOS app.

Implementation with custom splash screen timer:

1) Create a new view controller. Let’s name it `SplashViewController` that inherites from `UIViewController`. You don’t need to implement anything in the interface and implementation class.

2) Create a new nib file. Let’s name it `SplashView`. Open it with the Interface Builder and add a ImageView to the view. Then, assign a image you want to have for the splash screen to the image view (Inspector -> Attributes -> Image View -> Image).

3) Now, let’s add some code to the app delegate interface class first, so it looks like the example below:

```
@class SplashViewController;

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
     UIWindow *window;
     UINavigationController *navigationController;
     SplashViewController *splashViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SplashViewController *splashViewController;
@end
```

The only thing you have to do is to specify your splash view controller and add a property. Don’t forget to import SplashViewController by using @class.

4) Next, synthesize the splashViewController variable in your implementation class and extend the class by the following code:

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
     splashViewController = [[SplashViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashView" bundle:nil];
     [window addSubview:splashViewController.view];
     [window makeKeyAndVisible];
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5f target:self selector:@selector(onSlashScreenDone) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Initialize the splash view controller and add it as subview to the main window. Define your desired splash screen time with scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f (2.0 is 2 seconds).
Further, add the following method to the class:

```
-(void)onSlashScreenDone{
     [splashViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
     [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
     [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

The method `onSlashScreenDone` is called when the timer was expired. It removes the splash view controller and adds the follow up controller as subview and make it visible (in our example, a navigation controller).

I've used it in my app.. Let me know if more info needed. :)

Comment: just letting you know that the OP was not asking for this. OP asked why his view was not being removed from the superview upon button press. He is fully aware on how to add a subview to a page and how to set his view controllers. But hey thats a nice tutorial for a splash screen :)

Comment: @Pavan.. Yeah may be... but I tried to suggest a better approach for his intention. Let me know if m wrong somewhere.. :)

Comment: Although it is in the wrong post, its a nice piece of code for anyone that wants to make a splash screen. :D